# Flex IntelliJ Idea produces java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: flex2.tools.oem.internal.OEMConfiguration.setIncludeResourceBundles([Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, intellij-idea, flexbuilder, flex-builder-3

We have a project that builds fine with Flex Builder 3.

I installed a trial of IntelliJ Idea 10.5 to try and see if it makes the compilation faster. In IntelliJ you have 3 compiler options. With the 3rd one (Mxmlc/compc) it works, but compilation time doesn't improve.

I believe the first option (Built-in compiler shell) would improve the compilation a lot (using multiple threads) but then I get this error:

[(Flex Application 6)] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: flex2.tools.oem.internal.OEMConfiguration.setIncludeResourceBundles([Ljava/lang/String;)V

I am pointing IntelliJ to the same Flex SDK as Flex Builder/Eclipse is.

Thanks
Marcelo

Comment: It can't seem to find your resource bundle.  Are you sure you're specifying the properties alright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in compiler shell in IntelliJ IDEA doesn’t support ancient Flex SDK 3.0.0. Please consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flex 3 Ant build process with intellij to build with flex 3.
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html

It's a fair bit to learn how to use ant, but it can be used to streamline compilation of many languages, and you'll probably end up using it again in future projects.